# AngularJS directive data binding inside a popover

Tags: angularjs, popover, directive

Hi I'm creating an Angular bootstrap popover, and the popover contains a directive. The user story is that when the user clicks on a row inside an ui-grid table, the popover will show. But it seems that in HTML code the data is not actually passed into the directive. Related code is here:

search.tpl.html:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ui-grid="vm.selectedTypes" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-selection style="margin-top: 0px; z-index: 4; position: relative">
</div>

<script type="text/ng-templae" id="popover.html">
    <div style="z-index:10; position: relative">
        <type-view type="vm.type" domain="vm.domain" pos="{top: 0, left: 0}">
        </type-view>
    </div>
</script>
```

search.js:

```
//In configure
controllerAs: "vm",
...
//In controller
var vm=this;

vm.type=[...];
vm.domain=[...]; //both var get values inside
```

Now the popover is shown, and the directive is inside, but the values (vm.type and vm.domain) are not injected into the directive; I checked the console, and in the directive 'pos' is injected, so I suppose maybe it's because the scope is different inside a popover and directly using vm.sth will not work. How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Is vm a member of the scope, or are you using controllerAs? Need a bit more information.

Comment: Sorry didn't clarify; controllerAs: "vm"

Comment: Try putting {{vm.type}} in your template somewhere to see if the proper value is set. If it is set, and the binding is of type @, one guess is you might need to pass in type="{{vm.type}}"

Comment: Hmm I think for directives no need to include {{}} for params passed in; just using "vm.sth" should be the correct way.

Comment: It depends, an @ binding requires a literal value, so you need the @. If the binding is '=', '<' or &, then you wouldn't use the {{}}.

Comment: I see. But for this case if I include {{}} then things will go wrong: other attributes will not be recognized by the directive either.